# Class Template with variadic parameters and customizable traits

Tags: templates, c++11, sfinae, generic-programming, type-traits

I know that the title of this question isn't great.  I'd appreciate if someone can possible fix it to be more clear.

**A brief overview of my overall problem:**

I have a generic Factory class that I have designed which I've used for a number of projects.  The Factory class uses variadic parameters to allow me to specify 0 or more arguments that are passed to the constructor of the created classes.

When I originally designed this Generic_Factory class, I had no issue with returning the constructed class T as a std::shared_ptr.  However, new requirements have arisen and I'd like to adapt my Generic_Factory class to be more generic and allow the user of the factory to specify the type of pointer returned -- std::shared_ptr, std::unique_ptr, or T*.

**A working solution**

I've modified the Generic_Factory class by adding in another template argument.  I don't like this approach because (a) it doesn't allow me to specify a default behaviour and (b) I find that having the Pointer_Type as a template argument is a bit confusing when reading the code.  Nevertheless, it does work.  The tested Generic_Factory call is below, followed by a sample use of this class:

```
    template <class T>
    struct Shared_Pointer{
        using Type = std::shared_ptr<T>;
    };
    template <class T>
    struct Unique_Pointer{
        using Type = std::unique_ptr<T>;
    };
    template <class T>
    struct Raw_Pointer{
        using Type = T*;
    };


    template <
                class AbstractType, 
                template <typename> class Pointer_Type<AbstractType>,
                class...ConstructorArgs>
    class Generic_Factory{

    public:
        static typename Pointer_Type<AbstractType>::Type 
                Construct(std::string key, ConstructorArgs... arguments){
            auto it = Get_Registry()->find(key);
            if (it == Get_Registry()->cend())
                return nullptr;

            auto constructor = it->second;
            return constructor(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(arguments)...);
        }

        using Constructor_t = std::function<
                typename Pointer_Type<AbstractType>::Type(ConstructorArgs...)>;
        using Registry_t = std::map< std::string, Constructor_t>;

        Generic_Factory(Generic_Factory const&) = delete;
        Generic_Factory& operator=(Generic_Factory const&) = delete;

    protected:
        Generic_Factory(){}
        static Registry_t* Get_Registry();

    private:
        static Registry_t* _registry_;

    };

    template <
                class ConcreteType, 
                class AbstractType, 
                template <typename> class Pointer_Type<AbstractType>, 
                class...ConstructorArgs>
    struct Factory_Registrar : 
                private Generic_Factory<AbstractType, Pointer_Type, ConstructorArgs...>
                {
        using Factory = Generic_Factory<AbstractType, Pointer_Type, ConstructorArgs...>;
        using Constructor_t = typename Factory::Constructor_t;

public:
        Factory_Registrar(std::string const& designator, Constructor_t  object_constructor){
            auto registry = Factory::Get_Registry();
            if (registry->find(designator) == registry->cend())
                registry->insert(std::make_pair(designator, object_constructor));
        }
        unsigned int NO_OP(){ return 0; }
    };

    template <class Return_t, template <typename> class Pointer_Type, class...Args>
    typename Generic_Factory<Return_t, Pointer_Type, Args...>::Registry_t* Generic_Factory<Return_t, Pointer_Type, Args...>::Get_Registry(){
    if (_registry_ == nullptr)
        _registry_ = new Generic_Factory<Return_t, Pointer_Type, Args...>::Registry_t();
    return _registry_;
}

    template <class Return_t, template <typename> class Pointer_Type, class...Args>
    typename Generic_Factory<Return_t, Pointer_Type, Args...>::Registry_t* Generic_Factory<Return_t, Pointer_Type, Args...>::_registry_ = nullptr;
```

This generic class is used as follows:

```
class My_Abstract_Type; // Forward-declaration of abstract type
class Ctor_Arg1; // Forward declaration of arbitrary type, argument to constructor
class Ctor_Arg2; // Forward declaration of arbitrary type, argument to constructor

template <class ConcreteType>
using My_Factory_Registrar =
    Factory_Registrar<ConcreteType, My_Abstract_Type, Shared_Pointer, Ctor_Arg1&&, Ctor_Arg2 const&>;
using My_Factory =
    Generic_Factory<My_Abstract_Type, Shared_Pointer, Ctor_Arg1&&, Ctor_Arg2 const&>;
```

I use a macro for the boilerplate registration code in the concrete classes themselves.  It is just a static variable declaration:

```
class Concrete1{
   /* ...  */
   static My_Factory_Registrar<Concrete1>;
}
```

The definition of this variable would provide the key (string), and any additional parameters, if required.

**What I *really* want**

My ideal solution would use a traits class to eliminate the Pointer_Type template parameter.  I've made an attempt at this already, by creating a traits class with associated helper classes, but this isn't working properly.  My own attempt involved trying to specialize the traits class for each AbstractType (at least those that I wanted to be different from std::shared_ptr), but there were numerous problems with this.  Most of which I haven't even identified (wouldn't compile and the code just 'smells' wrong  -- I feel like it's the wrong approach and so I'm asking for some guidance before wasting a huge amount of time on something I really believe to be wrong.

I would really like to be able to use a declarative syntax similar to the rest of the use of the Generic_Factory class -- ideally another alias of some sort.

Any thoughts and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and best regards,
Shmuel

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of work and some additional thought, I've successfully make the code work by using the Traits approach, described in the section "What I *really* want".

A brief summary (I'll copy the full code below):

- I was trying to make my Generic_Factory even more generic -- allowing me to choose the type of pointer (I could probably expand this without much trouble to returning objects by value or reference).
- The easiest way was to add another template parameter, but I found this to be ugly:

  - No default parameters
  - Made the interface more confusing
- A traits-based approach would be ideal, but I was having troubles implementing this
- The main difficulty I had with the traits approach was the partial specialization of the Traits class itself.  This is usually in a different namespace than the factory code, plus, it doesn't lend itself to a declarative syntax, among other troubles.
- **After further thought, the object answer is that the Pointer_Type information used by the Traits class should be added directory to AbstractType. This makes complete sense and it appears to solve absolutely all of my troubles.**

The Traits part of the code follows below. For the full code, please refer to my [Github repository](https://github.com/ShmuelLevine/Generic_Factory):

```
   namespace internal{
    template <typename T, bool> struct Factory_Pointer_Traits_Impl;
    template<typename T> struct CheckForType;
    }

    template <typename T>
    struct Factory_Pointer_Traits
    {
        typedef typename internal::Factory_Pointer_Traits_Impl<T, internal::CheckForType<T>::value>::type pointer_t;
    };

    namespace internal {

        template <typename T, bool>
        struct Factory_Pointer_Traits_Impl
        {
            typedef Shared_Pointer<T> type;
        };

       template <typename T>
       struct Factory_Pointer_Traits_Impl<T, true>
       {
           typedef typename T::Pointer_Type type;
       };   

       template<typename T>
       struct CheckForType
       {
       private:
           typedef char                      yes;
           typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;   

           template<typename C> static yes test(typename C::Pointer_Type*);
           template<typename C> static no  test(...);
       public:
           static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
       };
    }
```

This required a new alias in the `Generic_Factory` class:

```
    template <class AbstractType, class...ConstructorArgs>
    class Generic_Factory{
        using Pointer_T = typename core::Factory_Pointer_Traits<AbstractType>::pointer_t::type;
    public:
        /* ... */
    };
```

Of course, all references to the old template template parameter `Pointer_Type` are replaced with the new alias, `Pointer_T`.

When declaring an abstract class for the root of a hierarchy for which I will have a Factory, a simple alias or typedef is required:

```
class IPerson{
    public:
        using Pointer_Type = Unique_Pointer<IPerson>;
        std::string first_name, last_name;
        /* ... */
    };
```

Alternative a macro can be used:

```
#define FACTORY_POINTER_TYPE(CLASS_NAME, POINTER_TYPE)  \
using Pointer_Type = fx::core::POINTER_TYPE<CLASS_NAME>;

class IPerson{
    public:
        FACTORY_POINTER_TYPE(IPerson, Unique_Pointer);
        std::string first_name, last_name;
        /* ... */
    };
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out an easy way to get rid of the `CLASS_NAME` parameter for the macro.  Perhaps something like boost::make_shared_from_this, and `decltype` or the like might work... I'm not sure if that's worth the effort.

I'd still like to hear any suggestions or feedback that you might have.

Thanks and regards,
Shmuel